# Using pipes in command line arguments

Tags: linux, pipe

I am working on an assignment on pipes in Linux. I have a program that prints `hello world`. It takes no argument.But when I run the program and provide command line arguments as `./a ls | wc`. I get the output `0 2 11` i.e. the output of `hello world` is passed through pipe to `wc`. Can someone please explain this behaviour.

Comment: What's to explain? Why wouldn't you expect it?

Comment: ...that question wasn't rhetorical: Unless we know what your current understanding is, how can we write an answer with certainty that we're addressing any issues with that understanding?

Comment: (If you're coming from Windows, you might be accustomed to a world where commands parse their own argument lists, given a string exactly as provided by the user. It doesn't work like that here: The shell parses the raw text, and the only thing a command gets is a C array of individual strings, one per argument).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I am new to shell and system programming so pardon me for such basic question. But still your answer was really helpful. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your program takes no arguments, the fact that you passed it `ls` as an argument *makes no difference to its output*: It's ignoring that argument and still emitting `hello world`, just as it would if `ls` had not been passed on its argument list.

---

Understand that a pipeline sets up a FIFO -- that is, it connects two programs.

```
./a ls ## this program's output...
wc     ## ...is connected to this program's input.
```

The pipeline is thus not an *argument* to `a`; it's an instruction to the shell about how to route the *output* of `a`, in this case an instruction to route it into the stdin of `wc`.